# How to access UI from CFRunLoopRun in ios

Tags: ios, cfsocket

how can i pop up a new view when i get commands in CFRunloop (connectCallBack) in CFSocket class.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're approaching the problem from the wrong side.

You should handle this new view poping up in when the correct (`kCFSocketConnectCallBack`) type of `CFSocketCallBack` is invoked.
Or possibly setting a flag there and handling view from main code.

You can have a `BOOL` flag called `popUpNConnectedView` that is initialized to `NO`.

You set it to `YES` in `connectCallBack` method. When your main loop sees it (at connection-oriented applications ther's usually some kind of a *haertbeat timer*) it pops up the view and clears the flag.

You didn't post any code so it's impossible to give you a more direct answer - you'll definetly find your answer here:

[Network Programming: Chapter 7 - iPhone SDK Application Development](http://oreilly.com/iphone/excerpts/iphone-sdk/network-programming.html)

And some more reading material:

[CFNetwork Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Networking/Conceptual/CFNetwork/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001132-CH1-DontLinkElementID_30)

Comment: thank u for ur reply. i would like to know if there is any other way rather than using NSTimer class to make changes in the UI or pop up new view. In my app what i need means, when i get popup request command from server i need to pop up new view.

Comment: You could do it immediatly from callback method. It depends on your viewController hierarchy. For example: you can make a popup method in your rootViewController and call this method (i.e. engagePopUp) from callback method.

Comment: using NSNotificationCenter i solved my problem thanks for support

Comment: You're welcome. Please consider adding your answer below (and accept it after 24hrs) - it might help someone else.